# Resusing jQuery functions

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a web project which is done using php and jQuery. All the jQuery functions are being stored in one .js file. All the modules of the project has similar functionality.

My problem is when a certain function is used for 2 or 3 times it stops working for other instances.
For example, to retrieve the clicked element's name first I was using

```
$('#articleCPanel #editorPanelActions input').click(function () {
    var actionName= ($(this).attr('name');
 });
```

but then after couple of modules this was no longer working. I had to use the below code instead

```
$('#videoCPanel #editVideo fieldset input').click(function(event) {
    var actionName = $(event.target).attr('name');
});
```

I would like to know is there any explanation for this?

I appreciate any help

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There can be no explanation for something posted without any context whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

I think it just comes down to conventions of the tags you are looking at. alt is commonly used on links (a tags), while name is not. So your first piece of code uses the alt tag of the link.

The second piece of code is only looking at input tags (presuming this is a textbox?). alt tags are not commonly associated with an input tag, but a name attribute would be used.

Without seeing the html (or php), your question is hard to answer.

Comment: well i accidentally posted 2 different code segments.I edited my post.It happens when accessing same inputs.well I was curious of why this is happening.anyway thanks alot for the explanation

Comment: if you copied this from your project, you should know you have an extra paren in the first example: ($(this).attr('name'); - doesn't need the first paren